# Ofuscar código em ActionScript 3.0 no SWF em Flash?

Tags: segurança, criptografia, actionscript-3, proteção

Encontrei este programa chamado [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) que efetua a engenharia reversa em arquivos *.SWF* convertendo-os para *.FLA*, deixando, inclusive, toda a programação do arquivo visível e aberta para o usuário.

Existe algum método de ofuscar o código dentro de um *.SWF* para que mesmo que usem este programa não seja possível decifrar ou ao menos tornar a compreensão mais difícil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diversas ferramentas para ofuscar SWF, tanto gratuitas quanto pagas, apenas escolha uma que te agrade. Segundo [essa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744367/520779), é preferível uma ferramenta que ofusque o próprio SWF que uma que ofusque os fontes em ActionScript, pois as que operam no arquivo compilado têm oportunidade de aplicar mais e melhores técnicas.

Cabe lembrar que nada do que você fizer vai tornar **impossível** decifrar seu código, apenas vai dificultar. De modo que não deve ser usado com o propósito de segurança (i.e. segurança por obscuridade), e sim para outros fins (dificultar um pouco a engenharia reversa no seu código, por exemplo). E sem querer ser chato, mas sugiro também fazer uma análise de risco para determinar o impacto real de alguém acessar seus fontes - pois na prática ele costuma ser bem menor do que se acredita, e acaba-se gastando tempo e dinheiro à toa em troca de pouco ou nenhum benefício.

Comment: Fiz um teste com o software no link da resposta do SOEN que você passou e atendeu bem as minhas expectativas, inclusive tornou o programa (Sothink SWF Decompiler) obsoleto! Também vou realizar uma análise de risco e efetuar outros testes! Muito obrigado pela sua resposta!