# *public class*, qual a sua função no action script?

Tags: actionscript-3

Bom pessoal, estou tentando aprender actionscript 3.0 para entender como o source de um jogo funciona, pois tem uma parte do script que não consigo achar uma explicação boa na internet que é o **public class**, no seguinte código:

```
package
{
    import mx.core.BitmapAsset;

    public class §_-6Ze§ extends BitmapAsset
    {


        public function §_-6Ze§()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

Teria como me explicar ?
Toda ajuda é bem vinda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine que eu tenha o seguinte código,

```
var meuBitmap:BitmapAsset = new §_-6Ze§();
```

Eu só consigo fazer isso sem ter erro de sintaxe porque:

- §_-6Ze§ é do tipo BitmapAsset
- §_-6Ze§ é uma classe pública
- §_-6Ze§ tem um construtor padrão público

Se uma classe é pública, qualquer um pode herdar desta classe, não importa qual seja o ponto no código.

Se um construtor é público e a classe a que ele pertence é pública, qualquer um pode instanciar essa classe com esse construtor.

Se um método é público e a classe a que ele pertence é pública, qualquer instância dessa classe pode chamar esse método público.

No seu exemplo, no construtor padrão de §_-6Ze§, existe uma palavra reservada, que é `super`. Ela faz referência à classe mãe da classe atual. Os `()` que se seguem demonstram uma chamada ao construtor padrão da classe mãe.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Embora eu baseie minha observação em suposição, acredito que esse tipo de nomenclatura `§_-6Ze§` está relacionada diretamente com algum [ofuscador de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6513/5043). Geralmente eles substituem o nome das classes do projeto por caracteres "estranhos", deixando a leitura mais difícil.